# Reading a big csv file in php, can't read all the file

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

so I'm trying to use PHP to read a large csv file (about 64 000 entries) and stack it in a big array

Using `fopen()` and `fgetcsv`, i managed to get most of the file read, though it suddenly stops at entry 51829 for no apparent reason

I checked in my array and in the CSV and the data get imported correctly, line 51829 in the csv and in the array are the same, etc...

any of you got an idea of why I can't read all the file?

Here's my code ^^ Thanks in advance

```
$this->load->model('Import_model', 'import');
$this->import->clear_student_group();



//CHARGER LE CSV
$row = 1;
$data = array();
$file = "Eleve_Groupe_Mat.csv";
$lines = count(file($file));

if ($fp = fopen('Eleve_Groupe_Mat.csv', 'r')) {
    $rownumber = 0;
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $rownumber++;
        $row = fgetcsv($fp);
        $datarow = explode(";", $row[0]);
        for($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
            $dataset[$rownumber][$i] = $datarow[$i];
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
$this->import->insert_student_group($dataset);
```

Comment: It's probably got an overflow of some kind. Try chunking your csv file into smaller pieces to overcome this.

Comment: bad idea, process it in chunks.

Comment: Are you doing any error checking inside `insert_student_group`? I don't think anybody can help you without more information on that. Have you activated error reporting?

Comment: What's the point of using fgetcsv() with the default , separator, then exploding on ; why not use fgetcsv() with a ; separator in the first place, then you can eliminate the explode and for loop completely

Answer (score 1):

Your script is probably running out of memory. Check your error logs or turn on error reporting to confirm. To make your script work you can try increasing the [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), which can be done either in [`php.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) or using [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php). But a much better approach would be not to store the csv data in an array at all, but rather process each line as you read it. This keeps the memory footprint low and alleviates the need for increasing the [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

Answer (score 1):

You're exhausting all the memory PHP has available to it.  A file that big can't fit into memory, especially not in PHP, which stores a lot of additional data with every variable created.

You should read a limited number of lines in, say 100 or so, then process the lines you've read in and discard them.  Then read the next 100 lines or so and repeat the process until you've processed the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

I think Fopen has restrictions on reading files. Try using file_get_contents();